# Why could Kakashi and Obito move while Naruto, Sasuke and even Kaguya couldn't?

Tags: naruto

Spoilers if you didn't see episode 472 of the anime yet:

> In episode 472, when Kaguya changed the environment to the world with high gravity, how come Kakashi and Obito could move while Naruto, Sasuke and even Kaguya couldn't?

I know they all used a lot of chakra fighting each other, but they are on a different level totally, and besides, Obito was half dead, and used almost all of his chakra to find Sasuke and bring him back.

Comment: I'm not sure how true this is or not. But when before Obito merged with the ten-tails he used his sharingan to make himself transparent - all attacks pass through him- by transporting to another dimension. So maybe they both used that dimension to free themselves of the gravity since they share it?

Comment: The will of fire i believe

Comment: My bet is on raw muscle. Kakshi and Obito theoretically would be the physically strongest ones there (especially with Kakashi having the Gates release), being adult males in their early 30s, and extremely fit. As well, those 2 had plenty of time to rest their muscles before that event while naruto and sasuke were fighting. No one there could use chakra to enhance strength either, just simulate or supplement it.

Comment: @Ryan Obito is half dead. After using all that kamui and the previous battle.

Comment: @Vahn your right, but kamui is a chakra/stamina consumer, not something that breaks down muscle, which is all he needs to overcome gravity. Obito did little phsyical fighting, focusing instead on chakra based fighting. Kakashi did a lot more physical fighting, but also has the first gate. I bet Guy and Lee could walk around in there at an almost leisurely pace without any weights on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many have mentioned the plothole part, however this seems to be a case of using a writing device to

> 1. Give Obito a heroic death
>  2. Absolve Obito of his crimes
>  3. Allow Kakshi to be cool by completing his Sharingan

**In Universe Explanation:**
This is the explanation written on the Wiki, a typical case of [Eleventh Hour Superpower](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EleventhHourSuperpower)

> Obito returns Sasuke and Sakura to the dimension where Naruto and Kakashi are. He watches as Naruto and Sasuke fight Kaguya, their combined powers the only ones capable of stopping her. Aware of this, Kaguya relocates them to a dimension with powerful gravity and pins Naruto and Sasuke down while she attacks with All-Killing Ash Bones. **Obito and Kakashi, empowered by a shared memory of their past friendship, place themselves in front of Naruto and Sasuke as shields.** Because his odyssey began by saving Kakashi from death by a boulder, Obito decides he must now end things by saving Kakashi's life again: he uses his left eye to teleport the attack aimed at Kakashi away, allowing the attack directed at him to connect. Obito's body begins to crumble and there is nothing anyone can do to save him. He warns Kakashi that he will not be around to save him a third time and places his faith for a better world in Naruto before dying with a smile.

This can be compared to a final push, the rush of adrenaline. Obito and Kakashi pushed themselves to the limit figuring they would die, while Naruto/Sasuke were still hoping to escape the Gravity pull so that they could continue fighting.

Answer (score 3):

Logical Explanation: Naruto and Sasuke had already jumped out of the way of the quicker first shots. Not only did they just expend great energy to move, they were also in terrible positions to attempt to get up. Whereas Kakashi and Obito had not been shot at, or even looked at, they had already stood up and could run. They were also able to freely infuse their chakra while Naruto, Sasuke and Kaguya were using theirs fighting each other. And then there was the mystical BS of Rin grabbing them and pulling them into position

Likely Truth: A plot hole by the writers in order to give Obito a noble death and introduce the idea that their team can somehow briefly help each other from beyond the grave to justify when Obito posthumously gave Kakashi both Mangekyo Sharingan for a temporary amount of time

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that would kinda sort of make sense is adrenaline. Like when a mother lifts a car to save her child type of thing.

Maybe there was some chakra involved, but it must have been mostly adrenaline, although Kakashi's was a bit more believable than Obito's. They are like his little brothers, plus he no longer had the Sharingan, so his energy would haven't have been drained and he is in incredible shape. I mean the way he works out is incredible; mountain climbing with one hand. But I haven't seen Obito do any physical exercising. But it needed to happen in order to get the story to go where they wanted it to, which is the real explanation for how they did it.

I actually came here looking for where the heck did Rin’s spirit come from that pulled them at the last second but with enough time for Kakashi to have a last-minute inner conversation with himself.

Answer (score -2):

Chakra is internal energy; it has nothing to do with physique (muscle, bones, skin, organs, etc.). Ninjas do not train their physical mortal bodies, besides special cases like Lee and Gai. The reason why Kakashi and Obito could move is because they have superior physique compare to Sasuke and Naruto, who have never trained their bodies before. Because gravity increases the weight of everything, chakra cannot help here. The only thing that can help is pure physical strength, and Kakashi had trained with Gai many times and was even able to open the first gate, meaning he is stronger physically.

This is also called the "Container" and the "Water". A ninja's essence is chakra, which is an energy located within the stomach and runs through the chakra network. So, in this case it is the water. The container is the body/physique of the ninja. A ninja does not need a strong body to become powerful, since chakra can be used to increase speed, jumping, power, etc., but remember that chakra does not change the structure of a ninja's body, such as bones, muscle, organs, etc. This is why Gai and Lee train their bodies so that when they open the gates it does not rip them apart. Sakura, for example, uses chakra control.

Kishimoto knows this, but the viewers don't, and he indirectly already confirmed body and chakra are different when he introduced Lee and Gai. Most viewers see chakra as more physical strength and more speed, but they don't realize that chakra and physique/body are completely different categories.

Example. Suppose that one denotes the following:
Level 1: Human Adult Male
Level 2: Bodybuilder Male/Power lifter

Then, an average ninja's body is of level 1, exactly as it was since the day they became able to extract chakra. Most future ninjas learn chakra extraction by the age of 4–7, which is the time they enter ninja school. Before learning chakra extraction, they are just normal humans: no super-strength or anything.

Naruto/Sasuke's body is of level 2, slightly higher even though they have never done training for physique, just because they are talented individuals and have bloodlines/tailed beast since birth.

Continuing the analogy in a similar manner, Kakashi is of level 4, since he trained to open the first gate.

Lee is of level 20, since he trained enough to make muscles, bones and body stronger to survive gates being release up to the sixth gate.

Gai is of level 30, since he can survive without breaking bones up to the seventh gate.

All ninjas can use chakra to directly enhance power/speed depending on their chakra levels and chakra control. Some, like Tsunade and Sakura, have extremely talented control, and are thus able to create similar feats of superhuman strength when they fight. Others like Kakashi are lower tier when they fight in close combat, as seen with his fight against Obito, while Lee and Gai do have stronger bodies, but because they have bad chakra control their increase in physical attributes from chakra enhancement is not similar to Tsunade and Sakura.